# Trying to use Mac dll (bundle) on Wine

Tags: macos, dll, bundle, wine, winelib

I'm currently trying to achieve (for my internship) to use Mac OS dll which are named Bundle (everthing is named bundle on mac ...) because the string comparison fonction from Wine is not working properly (gérard = gerard for example). It causes problems on databases because of the duplications.

Using a DLL to use the native comparison fonction of the OS would settle this problem. But unfortunately, there aren't a lot of documentations to implement properly a working Bundle DLL.

Until now (with my tutor), we succeeded to create a ".bundle" (which works perfectly fine) and then a ".so" but when using it under Wine, we got this error "Bad EXE Format for %1" which tell us that our dll is not in the right format because Wine need a spec file to use native DLL.

We found documentations to make a spec file on WineHQ website but we can't overcome this phase by just following the instructions [here](https://www.winehq.org/docs/winelib-guide/spec-file)(click sur "next" to have the following steps in the bottom right corner ...).

Has anyone ever succeeded (the only one person I saw do it, did  it in 2005 ...) to use mac OS DLL on wine and could help us ?

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I assume you don't know ...